# Convert date in a specific timezone to a timestamp in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, timezone, pytz

If I have something like "Apr 02, 2021" and (assuming it's listing as of noon PST), how would I convert this to an equivalent Unix epoch date, which I believe is a second figure in UTC time?

This was my attempt:

```
import time
import datetime
import pytz

print("Right now it's {}".format(int(time.time())))

date_string = "Apr 02, 2021"

d = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%b %d, %Y').replace(hour=12)
pacific_timezone = pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")
d_in_pacific_time = pacific_timezone.localize(d)

print("Noon PST on that day was {}".format(int(d_in_pacific_time.timestamp())))
```

I don't know if I am doing this correctly or if the method makes sense, time is always confusing for me and I am flying blind here. Is it correct to make a datetime, localize it to a pytz timezone, then convert it with `.timestamp()` which hopefully converts it to UTC?

Comment: Yes you're right, if you convert it back it would give you the correct output as you gave. `print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1617390000).astimezone(tz = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt
import pytz

pacific_timezone = pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")
date = dt.datetime(2021, 4, 2, tzinfo=pacific_timezone)  # Apr 2, 2021
posix_time = date.timestamp()  # seconds since Jan 1, 1970
```

You can verify that this works by testing `date = dt.datetime(1970,1,1,tzinfo=dt.timezone.utc)`.

Specifying `tzinfo` makes `date` an "aware" datetime object, which is why you can compare it to other datetime objects as is done in the `timestamp()` method.  From the docs:

```
timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)).total_seconds()
```